# Symfony url for image

Tags: php, jquery, image, url, symfony1

I need to obtain the final url for an image to set it as parameter to a JQuery Datepicker input. The way to declare the DatePicker is:

```
$("#myInput").datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "<url-for-the-image>",
    buttonImageOnly: true
});
```

I know in symfony the images are located (by default) in the `/web/images` directory, and this can be accessed with `sfConfig::get('sf_web_dir').'/images'`.

The probelm is that this function returns me something like `/var/www/.../web/images` instead of `http://-IP-ADDRESS-/.../web/images`.

How can i do it to find the correct url for an image in my image directory? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, solved! just using this Symfony function: `image_path('my-image.png');` This returns the path to the image!